# Creating an associative array from MySQL Query Results - Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and I need to use a plugin for a calendar that needs to pass some values as follows:

JS

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: Routing.generate('example'),
   data: {},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {

    $('#calendar').eCalendar({
    ...
    events: [{
       title: 'Example Title 1', 
       description: 'Description 1.', 
       datetime: new Date(2016, 11, 30) 
    },
    {
       title: 'Example Title 2', 
       description: 'Description 2.', 
       datetime: new Date(2016, 10, 23), 
    }]
  });
 }
})
```

These events data can be passed as follows via ajax:

JS

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: Routing.generate('example'),
   data: {},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {

    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i = i + 1) {
      str=response.data[i].datetime.date;

      year=str.substring(0,4);
      month=str.substring(5,7);
      day=str.substring(8,10);

      var myDate = new Date(year,month-1,day);
      response.data[i].datetime = myDate;
    }

    $('#calendar').eCalendar({
    ...
    events: response.data
  });
 }
})
```

PHP

```
public function exampleAction()
{

 $arr = array(array("title" => 'Example Title 1',"description" => "Description 1.","datetime"=>new \DateTime("now")),
        array("title" => 'Example Title 2',"description" => "Description 1.","datetime"=>new \DateTime("now"))
    );

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'data' =>$arr,
        'success' => true), 200);
}
```

So far so good. But now I need to get that data from the following table in the database:

```
id  title               description     datetime                   category     hour    
1   Example Title 1     Description 1.  2016-12-21 00:00:00     general     all day     
2   Example Title 2     Description 2.  2016-12-21 00:00:00     general     09:00
```

In my Repository class I use the following code to query:

```
public function findEvents($category) //$category has the searched value passed from the controller.
{
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT e FROM BackendBundle:Events e WHERE e.category=:category ORDER BY e.datetime ASC, e.hour ASC')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'category' => $category))
    ->getResult();
}
```

But now I do not know how I can get an array associative only with the values of some columns, like this example:

```
 $arr = array(array("title" => 'Example Title 1',"description" => "Description 1.","datetime"=>new \DateTime("now")),
        array("title" => 'Example Title 2',"description" => "Description 1.","datetime"=>new \DateTime("now"))
    );
```

Comment: Use partial `SELECT PARTIAL e.{title, description, etc} FROM ...`

Comment: You could try `return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT e.title, e.description, e.date FROM BackendBundle:Events e WHERE e.category=:category ORDER BY e.date ASC, e.hour ASC')->setParameters(array('category' => $category)) ->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Comment: Thanks @Garry, I got this by adding what you tell me, except `Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` that gave error (I do not know what it's for). The problem I have not mentioned before is that I need to add the text in the hour column to the end of the value of the title column (Example: Title1. | 09:00), so what I wanted to do was get all the columns and Then modify it and create the modified associative array. How could I add that information?

Comment: `Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` is a constant that returns the result as an array rather than an array of entities.  I use Doctrine with Zend Framework 2 so I don't know how to do this in Symfony.

Comment: To get the title and time you need to use CONCAT in your select something like this `SELECT e.title, e.description, e.date, CONCAT(CONCAT(e.title, ' '), e.date) AS titledate`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Garry, this is just what I needed. Regarding the above I also use doctrine 2, but I get this error:`Error: Class &#039;BackendBundle\Entity\Doctrine\ORM\Query&#039; not
 found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/src/BackendBundle/Entity/EventsRepository.php` 
If you see why the error occurs tell me, otherwise do not worry as it works perfect that.

Comment: Try using \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY. Note the \ at the beginning.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you @Garry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally thanks to @Garry I was able to solve my problem with the following code:

```
public function findEvents($category) //$category has the  searched value passed from the controller.
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
   'SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(e.title, ' '), e.date) AS title, e.description, e.datetime FROM BackendBundle:Events e WHERE e.category=:category ORDER BY e.datetime ASC, e.hour ASC')
   ->setParameters(array(
    'category' => $category))
   ->getResult();
}
```

In addition to getting only the values of the three columns I needed, I was able to add the date to the title (which I had not indicated earlier in the question).